# How to view in-memory graph in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-data-science

Is it possible to call an in-memory graph (projected graph) in a way that returns a graph (not only Table, Text & Code) in `Neo4j` database?

Answer (score 1):

Currently not possible.
A feature request phase.

https://community.neo4j.com/t/visualizing-in-memory-graph/44436